# Как сделать запись в БД без перезагрузки страницы PHP, JS AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Из формы данные обрабатываются скриптом, отправляются на сервер без перезагрузки страницы и выводятся в новом div

```
<script>
  var scrolltootverstie = 0;
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('button.otverstiesubmit').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault() // без перезагрузки страницы
   var otverstiex = $('input.otverstiex').val();
   var otverstiey = $('input.otverstiey').val();
   var otverstiediametr = $('input.otverstiediametr').val();

   $.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "add-otverstie.php",
   data: { otverstiex: otverstiex, otverstiey: otverstiey, otverstiediametr: 
   otverstiediametr },
                                                                
   success: function() {
   scrolltootverstie = scrolltootverstie + 1;

   let html = `
   <div>
     <p id="${scrolltootverstie}">Отверстие</p>
     <div class="form-group">
       <span>Расстояние от левого края панели до центра отверстия по оси X, мм</span><br>
       <p>${otverstiex} мм</p>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <span>Расстояние от левого края панели до центра отверстия по оси Y, мм</span><br>
       <p>${otverstiey} мм</p>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <span>Диаметр отверстия, мм</span><br>
       <p>${otverstiediametr} мм</p>
     </div>
     
     <button>Удалить</button>
   </div>
  `;

$("#showotverstie").append(html);

const el = document.getElementById(`${scrolltootverstie}`);
el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
                                                                    
var lookotverstiey = otverstiey / 10;
var lookotverstiex = otverstiex / 10;
let otvar = `
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: ${lookotverstiey}px; left: ${lookotverstiex}px; width: ${otverstiediametr}px; height: ${otverstiediametr}px;"></div>  
`;
                                                                    $("#lookotverstie").append(otvar);
}
})
})
})
</script>
```

Какую функцию нужно привязать к кнопке "Удалить" в добавленном div, чтобы запись удалялась и отображение соответственно тоже?

Comment: При создании добавлять `id`. `div id="myDiv"` и далее удалять как обычно `var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
 elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);`

Comment: var let const.. zestoko odnako) 
id дайте div, после чего удалите весь блок) На кнопку удалить можете создать событие как вы это сделали при добавлении, либо тупо дать кнопке атребут onclick="func(id)" с функцией, в которую передаете id

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Заголовок говорит о том, что должно быть в файле **add-otverstie.php**? Удаляться должно из БД или только из выводимой в HTML таблице?

Comment: @DrMcSheen нужно ещё отправить запрос в БД на удаление элемента

Comment: @Опан запись должна удаляться из БД и HTML

Answer (score 0):

Отправьте на сервер запрос, какую запись удалять. Для примера - параметры phone, pass.

```
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "https://ваш_сайт/del-otverstie.php";
    element1.value = phone;
    element1.name = "phone";
    element1.type = "hidden";
    form.appendChild(element1);
    element2.value = "<?php echo $pass?>";
    element2.name = "pass";
    element2.type = "hidden";
    form.appendChild(element2);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
```

А там встречайте в del-otverstie.php

```
include_once 'подключение_к_базе.php';
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
// и запрос на удаление как обычно
DELETE FROM ...
```

Comment: Но так отправка из формы происходит сразу после загрузки формы. Не успеете ввести данные.

Comment: Это всего лишь способ отправки данных. Таким же образом можно отправить с помошью `ajax`, никакой разницы.

Answer (score -1):

Похоже, что в файле **add-otverstie.php** должно быть предусмотрено и добавление и удаление строки БД. Для этого должны из формы и из кнопки удаления отправляться два разных соответствующих значения какого-то эдентификатора того, что нужно сделать.
Вывод HTML-таблицы со всеми записями в БД и с кнопками удаления удобней формировать тоже в файле add-otverstie.php, а в файле, где находится форма отправки, получать эту таблицу таким образом:

```
success: function(data) {
    let html = data.responseText;
    $("#showotverstie").append(html);
}
```

Кнопка удаления должна быть в отдельной форме и при её нажатии должно с помощью ajax передаваться ID или другой уникальный параметр строки в БД, которую нужно удалить. Не буду писать весь код, это уже из области фриланса.